# OnClick increase textarea rows

Tags: textarea, onfocus

Id like to have a smiple html textarea that when clicked (i guess onFocused) will change its rows="1" property to rows="10."  I am pretty sure this can be done with javascript, but im not sure how.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<textarea rows="1" onclick="this.rows = '10';"></textarea>
```

If you want to increase number of rows when textarea is selected by another way for e.g. tabulator you should use `onfocus` instead of `onclick`, and if you wanna decrease rows when losing focus, you should use something like `this onblur="if(this.value == '') this.rows = '1';"` - Because when you once type text into the textarea, and click out of it, the textarea may shrink to 1 row and your text will be not readeable. This prevents this behavior - only shrink when textarea is empty.

Comment: +1 and I imagine you'd want a `onblur="this.rows='1';"` if you want the reverse when it's it is clicked out of.

Comment: Something to note. The above will not resize back to one row if the textarea is manually resized via the handle. When this action happens, height is applied via inline styling. A fix for this behavior is to clear the `style=' '` attribute as well. This can be done inline via `onblur='this.rows='1'; this.style=" ";'` or a JQuery onblur function via `$(this).css({ height: '' });`.